Footnotesep not doing anything
I´m trying to move down the footnote relative to the main text body, but it won´t move. I´m using geometry so i tried footnotesep but it doesn't work. I´m also using fancyhdr which might be interferring with this.
Here is my code, most of it is not important but since i don't know the cause i thought I would insert it all. Also the second fancypagestyle (documentstyle) I´m using for a later part of the work and I have the same issue there:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[
paperheight=29.7cm,
paperwidth=21cm,
left=3cm,
right=2.5cm,
top=3cm,
bottom=4cm,
footnotesep = 2cm
]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}


\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{MA24}
\fancyhead[R]{PLA, Technische Produktion}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}


\fancypagestyle{documentstyle}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[L]{MA24}
    \fancyhead[R]{PLA, Technische Produktion}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[L]{Flurin Maissen, 6Gb}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}
}


%def titelseite

\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}
\pretitle{\centering\huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\vspace{20mm}}
\preauthor{%
  \centering
  \scalebox{2}{
\chemfig{-[@{op,0.5}:33](-[:90])(-[:-33](=[:-90]O)((-[:33]O(-[@{cl,0.5}:-33]))))}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]}, height=40pt, depth=40pt, indice=\!n]{op}{cl}
}\par
  \vspace{20mm}\large
}
\postauthor{\par}

\title{Synthetisierung von PLA \\ mit Milchsäure}
\author{Flurin Maissen, 6Gb \\
  Betreuerperson: Rocco Ciorciaro, Chemie \\
  Maturaarbeit 2024, Technische Produktion \\
  Bündner Kantonsschule, Gymnasium}

\date{}


%start dokument

\begin{document}

%titelseite

\maketitle 

%vorworte etc.

\chapter*{Abstract}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut aliquam purus sit amet. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut aliquam purus sit amet. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut aliquam purus sit amet. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque. Suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in.


Your example is incomplete and therefore neither does compile nor has any \footnote{…}. So you issue is unclear. Please try to show a minimal working example from \documentclass to \end{document} that allows us to reproduce your issue. Currently I can only guess, that you mix up page footer and footnotes. Note: Instead of copying lipsum text, you can use a package like lipsum to generate the dummy text with short commands.

when you fix your example to show the problem please also avoid long lines so the code can be seen in this site's default text width without having to scroll the block right to see if there are any relevant commands not shown. You have tagged this header-footer and your example has examples of page header setup but your question asks about \footsep which is unrelated to page styles and relates to footnotes but you have no footnotes in the example???

Do you maybe mean footskip rather than footnotesep? And, by the way, it is better to put headheight also in the geometry options instead of defining it separately.
